# SSDT Register Data Tier Application

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-data-tools, database-project

I am having problems publishing a SSDT database project and registering it as a data tier application. Let me explain.

I have a database (A) which references two other databases (B & C) through linked servers. I have created projects based on B and C and snapshoted the projects to create dacpac's for databases B and C. I have created a database project for database A which has database references to B and C through dacpac's. I have set SQLCMD variables and modified the db project ddl scripts to use the SQLCMD variables in place of the un-resolved linked server names. The project builds!

I am trying to publish the project as a data tier application but keep receiving the following error "Databases registered as a DAC database must be hosted by an instance of SQL 2005 SP4, SQL 2008 SP2, SQL 2008 R2, SQL 2012 or SQL Azure". Incidentally I am running SQL server 2012.

I thought I would test whether I could register as a data tier application through SSMS. Within SSMS the option to "Register as data Tier Application" is grayed out. I therefore tried to "Export Data Tier Application" and received a number of error in reference to the linked server objects.

My question is; is  it possible to deploy a SSDT database project and register it as a Data Tier Application where the project is using linked servers, or am I doing something wrong? If it is possible could some one provide some advice.

I have broken Google looking for the answer, so any help would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this ? Hitting the same problem.

Comment: I never did find a solution to this problem. I asked the same question here [link](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/40879/registering-a-ssdt-database-project-as-a-data-tier-application-fails) and unfortunately got no joy. It appears as though this is just one of the many problems with SSDT, that is not to say that SSDT is not a great tool; it is; but it does have issues. If you have more luck than me please drop a resolution link in this thread. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had this error recently so I'll add my solution for anyone else who comes across this, already added to the [dba stack exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/40879/registering-a-ssdt-database-project-as-a-data-tier-application-fails)

Turns out in my publish.xml I had RegisterDataTierApplication set to True. The first time I published the database it worked fine, but then I got the same error, as the database was already registered as a Data Tier application.

By setting to false (or unchecking the checkbox in the gui) it works fine.